# PDF file getting corrupted after clob been written as PDF file in Java

Tags: java

I am using hibernate to insert a pdf file as bytes into database using the below code.

```
File file = new File("D:\\test.pdf");
byte[] imageData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(imageData);
fileInputStream.close();
emp.setClobdata(new String(imageData));
session.save(emp);
```

Then I am trying to write the file from database to a pdf file. Using the below code. But the pdf is getting corrupted.

```
Emp emp = (Emp) session.get(Emp.class, 2);
byte[] b = emp.getClobdata().getBytes();
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\some.pdf");
fout.write(b); fout.flush();
```

What I am doing wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you say more about your database?

Answer (score 2):

pdf files are binary, you should be using a BLOB not a CLOB.

also, when you read from the file, you need to use something like `DataInputStream.readFully` to ensure you are reading all the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried using BLOB in my database. Still issue exists. Could you be bit more specific about DataInputStream.readFully that would really help me.

Comment: The updated code is same. All I did was changed the database field type as BLOB. I am experiencing problems with the above mentioned code snippets

Comment: @user3173304 - if your code is the same, then you missed a key point.  the data is _binary_, so you should be treating it as _bytes_ exclusively, not _chars_ (or String).